# AzureWebApp@1 task in Azure pipeline deleting files from previous deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, pipeline

I am attempting to set up some Azure pipelines to build and deploy some WebJobs.  The build and deployment seem to work fine.  Until I run it a second time.  We have about 20 WebJobs running on the same Azure Web App.  These perform background tasks for our application.

Scenario:

- WebJob1 has a pipeline (YML below).  It runs and builds and deploys the files just fine.
- WebJob2 has a pipeline (same YML below, just a different job name).  It runs and builds and deploys the files just fine...BUT,  during the deploy step for this job, all of the files deployed for WebJob1 are deleted.  If I then run the pipeline again for WebJob1, it builds and deploys fine but all the files for WebJob2 are deleted.

I searched quite a bit and I am unable to figure out this behavior.  Something cached, some cleanup step?  I can't figure out why one would step on the other.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

The YML file below is the same for both pipelines, the only difference is the jobName.

Edit:  For clarity..

When WebJob1 deploys, the files are properly deployed to c:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Triggered\WebJob1.

When WebJob2 deploys, the files are properly deployed to c:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Triggered\WebJob2.

..but when WebJob2 deploys, it also deletes the files in the WebJob1 directory

```
trigger:
- DEV

pool:
  name: Dev Pipeline Pool

variables:
  - name: jobName
    value: TestWebJob
  - name: jobType
    value: Triggered
  - name: serviceConnectionToDeployTo1
    value: devApp-sc
  - name: appServiceName
    value: devApp

resources:
   repositories:
   - repository: WebJobLib
     type: git
     name: WebJobLib
     ref: master

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: WebJobLib

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run dotnet build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: --configuration release
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run dotnet publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: --output $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/publish_output/app_data/Jobs/$(jobType)/$(jobName)
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: Archive published output
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/publish_output
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: zip
    archiveFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    verbose: true

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  displayName: Azure Web App Deploy
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionToDeployTo1)
    appType: webApp
    appName: $(appServiceName)
    package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    deploymentMethod: auto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build your **`webjobs`** separately in the **`app folder`** and publish its **`artifact`** in the **`Azure Web App`** like below:-

***My build pipeline:-***

I have built the **`2 Webjobs separately`** with **`DotNetCoreCl@2`** command:-

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/Webjob1.csproj'
      arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/WebJob1'
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: false

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: true
      projects: '**/WebJobExample.WebJob.csproj'
      arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/WebJobExample'
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: false
```

***Complete yaml pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job: BuildAndDeployWebJobs
  displayName: 'Build and Deploy Web Jobs'

  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.x'
      installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/Webjob1.csproj'
      arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/WebJob1'
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: false

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: true
      projects: '**/WebJobExample.WebJob.csproj'
      arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/WebJobExample'
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: false

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'

  - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
    inputs:
      ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
      azureSubscription: 'subscription (xxxxxxxxxe97xxxxx2a7)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      WebAppName: 'valleywebapp92'
      packageForLinux: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I see now that when AzureWebApp@1 runs using zip deploy, the archive must contain all the apps I want deployed - like in your example above. I cannot have one deploy for one app and then another deploy for a second because of the cleanup behavior.